# How to create and test a jar file in scala IDE?

Tags: java, scala, jar

I have two .java files, i was create jar for two java files. Jar is loaded into ScalaIDE project. But jar file cannot be loaded i was calling a jar one of the (.java file) method in scala. Runtime exception occurs. one of the .java file look like that..

```
package com.test;
public class call
{

    public int printOne() {
        return 100;
    }

    public int printTwo() {
        return 200;
    }
}
```

From scala i call the method...,

```
 val sm = new call()
     val res =  sm.printOne()
```

error throws type not found. Pls help me to find solution Thank you

Comment: Have you import com.test.call? in the Scala code?

Comment: @Luong Ba Linh First thing is , i couldn't able view my package through import statement. I did, my jar is in lib folder then i did right click it add to build path , jar move to referenced libraries.